# How to proceed after upgrade error ee2 to 3?

Tags: database, ee2-upgrades, config

I am upgrading from Expression Engine 2 to 3. The upgrade was stopped and the following is the message I received:

Error While Installing 3.4.1 Stopped
Oops, there was an error

ExpressionEngine appears to already be installed on your database, even though your config file is blank. If you are attempting to update ExpressionEngine from a previous version restore your config file first, then run this installation wizard again.

HOW DO I PROCEED?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

EE2 and EE3 have their config files in different directories. Did you do these two things?

Copy system/expressionengine/config/config.php to system/user/config/config.php
Copy system/expressionengine/config/database.php to system/user/config/database.php

From https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/upgrade_from_2.x.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't done the two things you suggested. I will try doing it.

Comment: Many thanks for answer, it was spot on. It all works.

Comment: Glad it worked, can you mark this answer as completed?